# Problems with Computing the Friedmann Equation

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, simulations

I am trying to write a program which uses the Friedmann equation to graph the expansion of a universe given the starting parameters $K$ (geometry of spacetime), $R$ (curvature of spacetime) and $\rho$ (average mass density). So far, I have rearranged the equation to the form:

$$\frac{dt}{da} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{8}{3}\pi G \rho a^2 - K\frac{c^2}{R^2}}}$$

I then input this equation into Wolfram Alpha and integrated it, yielding the result:

$$t = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}\log{\left(\sqrt{2\pi\rho G}\sqrt{8\pi a^2 \rho G - \frac{3c^2K}{R^2}}+4\pi a \rho G\right)}}{2\sqrt{\rho G}} + C$$

The program then plots values of $t$ for values of $a$ ranging from $0.5$ to $1.5$, inclusive.

The problem I have is that, when I run the program, it doesn't work. When $K = 1$, all of the values come out as `NaN`. When $K = -1$, all of the values of $t$ came out the same and, when $K = 0$, when given the values of our universe, it doesn't look as expected.

I have a feeling that there is a problem in my rearrangement and subsequent integration of the Friedmann equation, but I don't know enough calculus to know where I have gone wrong.

Can someone guide me on what I am doing wrong?

---

I have been testing this with $R = 1$ and $\rho = 9 \times 10^{-27} kgm^{-3}$.

### Edit:

Following [Frederich Thomas' advice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/351393/problems-with-computing-the-friedmann-equation?noredirect=1#comment785764_351393), I have now adjusted the equation to:

$$t = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}\log{\left(\sqrt{2\pi\rho G}\sqrt{|8\pi a^2 \rho G - \frac{3c^2K}{R^2}|}+4\pi a \rho G\right)}}{2\sqrt{\rho G}} + C$$

At $K = 1$, the values no longer come out as `NaN` but they are now like $K = -1$ where all of the values of $t$ are the same.

Comment: Looking at your solution for $t$ reminds me why it's good to use units where $8 \pi G = c = 1$.

Comment: On a more serious note:  what values are you using for $\rho$ and $R$?  This may just be an issue of inconsistent units.  I also note that your solution is only valid when $\rho$ is constant, which is true for vacuum energy but won't get you the matter-dominated or radiation-dominated cosmological histories of our Universe up to this point.

Comment: check if the expression under square root is positive. The same applies to the argument of the logarithm, it should be better positive, and check of course if all your variables have defined values. Finally, why using Mathematica? Matlab makes better plots without requiring a long list of plot attributes for make it nice.

Comment: I thought the solutions involved sinh & cosh?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert The values I've been using are $R = 1$ (I don't know what the units are) and $\rho = 9 \times 10^{-27} kgm^{-3}$

Comment: @FredericThomas I'm actually using Javascript. I just used Wolfram Alpha for the integration

Comment: What is your integration constant $C$ ?  Your program can't do nothing if you don't specify this constant.  Also, since $\rho = \mathrm{constant}$, you should use a much simpler parametrization, that should look like an exponential function : $a(t) = a_0 \, e^{\lambda \, t}$ (this is for $K = 0$, i.e. flat space).

Comment: @Someone My constant of integration is set such that when $a = 1$, $t = 13.8$ billion years (where $t$ is in seconds)

Comment: Then what graphics you want to plot ?  I think it's easier if you have $a(t)$ instead of $t(a)$.

Comment: For $\rho = \mathrm{constant}$, the general solution for $k = -1, 0, +1$ can be cast into the following form : \begin{equation}
  a(t) = a(0) \cosh{\omega t} \pm \sqrt{\displaystyle{a^2(0) - k \, \ell_{\Lambda}^2}} \: \sinh{\omega t},
 \end{equation} where $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}$, $\ell_{\Lambda} \equiv \frac{1}{\omega}$ and $\rho = \frac{\Lambda}{8 \pi G}$.

Comment: @Someone That's extremely helpful, thanks. Does $a^2(0)$ mean $a(a(0))$ or does it means $(a(0))^2$?

Comment: $a^2(0)$ means $(a(0))^2$.  You can set $a(0) = 1$ if you wish, since the units for the scale factor are arbitrary.

Comment: @Someone Since you have solved my problem, it might be worth adding this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you want to solve is the first equation of Friedmann-Lemaitre :
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\dot{a}^2 \equiv \Big( \frac{d a}{d t} \Big)^2 = \frac{8 \pi G}{3} \, \rho \, a^2 - k,
\end{equation}
where $k = -1, 0, 1$ for *open*, *euclidian* and *closed* space, respectively.  You first need to assume some state of matter : $\rho \equiv f(a)$.  For example $\rho \propto a^{- 3}$ for *dustlike* matter or $\rho \propto a^{- 4}$ for *pure radiation*.  If you impose $\rho = \mathrm{constant}$, then this is like imposing an empty space with a *cosmological constant* only.  It is then preferable to write
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\rho = \frac{\Lambda}{8 \pi G}.
\end{equation}
The solution to the following differential equation is well known :
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\Big( \frac{d a}{d t} \Big)^2 = \frac{\Lambda}{3} \, a^2 - k,
\end{equation}
with solution
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
a(t) = a_0 \cosh{\omega t} \pm \sqrt{a_0^2 - \frac{3 k}{\Lambda}} \, \sinh{\omega t},
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\tag{5}
\omega \equiv \sqrt{\frac{\Lambda}{3}}.
\end{equation}
Since the scale factor is defined up to an arbitrary constant factor, you can set $a_0 = \sqrt{\frac{3}{\Lambda}} \equiv \omega^{-1}$ if $k = 1$ or $k = 0$, and $a_0 = 0$ if $k = -1$, so that (4) becomes
\begin{align}
a(t) = \omega^{-1} \cosh{\omega \, t}, \qquad \text{if $k = 1$}.  \tag{6}\\[12pt]
a(t) = \omega^{-1} e^{\pm \, \omega \, t}, \qquad \text{if $k = 0$}.  \tag{7}\\[12pt]
a(t) = \omega^{-1} \sinh{\omega \, t}, \qquad \text{if $k = -1$}.  \tag{8}
\end{align}
These solutions describe an *empty deSitter universe*, with a positive cosmological constant, which can be viewed as a *vacuum dominated universe*.